# $ is not defined getting error in my application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux

I am getting this error `$ is not defined` in my application.I am using this `npm` package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zoomus/websdk

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-dew-ut22z?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { ZoomMtg } from "@zoomus/websdk";

ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

API link

https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web/getting-started/quickstart

Comment: are you sure all the resources are actually accessible on appropriate url paths like the link you provided suggests?

Comment: yes I also added `jquery`...please check codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

The way you added jquery to the project is wrong, the dependency does not require you to add a react interface to the jquery, instead you are supposed to add it to the global scope, equivalent of link and script tag in index.html.

So all you have to do is edit your index.html file in the public folder and add the said link, for instance using cdn:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The piece of code you've provided deos not seem to even attempt at exposing the files requiered by the dependency, which is why i used the cdn library.

Please note that the dependency also asks you to make other files available, such as:

- `node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/bootstrap.css`
- `node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/react-select.css`

which may cause an issue later in the project developement